# Setting quota limit for a service account on Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

We've a project and a service account under it that is used for all our calls to BQ. We would like to set a limit of 1TB per day quota for that specific account. Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BigQuery custom quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/cost-controls#controlling_query_costs_using_bigquery_custom_quotas) enable you to specify a limit on the number of bytes processed per day, in 10 TB increments. (*Note, the minimum is 10TB increments, not 1TB*). The [BigQuery Custom Quota Request form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/bigquery_custom_quota_request_form) should be used in this case.

You can set quotas at **project-level** or at **user-level**. User-level quotas are applied to all users (including service accounts) in the project.

If you have many users that make BQ calls in the same project, I would recommend you to create another project only with the service account, set the project-level limit to **10TB** per day, and then allow access to this project from your original project. This way you can better control the cost, and you might save a lot of time.

Also you can check these [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) for controlling costs.

Comment: Thanks @Xiaoxia. I already have the info from the documentation, but wasn't aware we could provide access between projects like you have mentioned. This will help. I'll give it a try.

Comment: would you know how to give access between projects? I don't see an option to do it in the console.

Comment: You have to add the service account ID (from the newly created project) to IAM session in the original project, with the correspond role(s).